# como almacenar el resultado de un query en formato csv, con java?

Tags: java, spring, csv

Tengo el siguiente método en mi controller, el cual recupera datos del formulario y los pasa como parámetros al método del servicio para obtener el resultado del query, lo que necesito es mostrar el resultado del query en un archivo csv y que se descargue, pero no se como, que librería se ocupa?
que necesito?

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/formulario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String obtieneDatos(@ModelAttribute("consultaForm") Factura fact, Model model) {
        
        String id = fact.getId();
        String cvePag=fact.getClavePago();
        Date fecha = fact.getFechaInicial();
        
 List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
        
       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sólo se trata de generar CSV, lo más fácil es que hacer algo así:

```
class Factura {

    public String toCSVRepresentation() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder
            .add(getAttr1()).append(";")
            .add(getAttr2()).append(";")
            ....
            .add(getAttrN()).append(";");
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Y en tu controller, después de la llamada al servicio, haces esto:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/formulario", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/csv")
public void obtieneDatos(@ModelAttribute("consultaForm") Factura fact, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
   String id = fact.getId();
   String cvePag=fact.getClavePago();
   Date fecha = fact.getFechaInicial();

   List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);

   response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv");
   try {
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.write("nombreCol1;nombreCol2;...;nombreColN;");
       out.write("\n");

       //Versión para Java 8
       //factList.forEach(result -> {
       //    out.write(result.toCSVRepresentation());
       //    out.write("\n");
       //});
       for(Factura result: factList) {
           out.write(result.toCSVRepresentation());
           out.write("\n");
       }

       out.flush();
       out.close();
   } catch (IOException ix) {
       throw new RuntimeException("There was an error while retrieving CSV data", ix);
   }
```

}

Si ya también tuvieses que hacer importación de CSVs, entonces se podría usar una librería como Jackson Dataformat (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv) y podrías usarla para ambos procesos.

Comment: Ojo, ese codigo solo funciona en Java8 y sucesivos. El OP puede estar usando un Java inferior

Comment: Tienes razón. Aunque sólo es el recorrido de una lista, voy a cambiarlo

Comment: Ya lo implemente, pero en mi clase entidad al momento de crear el método String toCSVRepresentation, y hacer el build.add(getaAtributo()).add(“;”);  me marca error en el primer .add, dice el método add is undefinided for the Type StringBuilder

Comment: Leches, disculpas... no es `add`, es `append`. Ahora lo edito en la solución.

Comment: Ya lo implemente y si descarga el archivo, solo que al abrirlo me sale un mensaje de Excel que dice export.csv is a SYLK file, but cannot load it. The file has errors y al abrirlo me muestra el resultado pero también todo el HTML de mando página, pongo la imagen

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto: https://annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk/ Igualmente, ¿has probado a grabar el archivo y abrirlo con un editor de texto como Notepad? Ah, y por si acaso, al método del controlador quítale el String como return type de la cabecera y déjalo a void. Se me ha colado eso cuando he modificado tu código y, aunque no lo creo, tal vez tenga algo que ver

Comment: ya cheque lo del error de excel y ya quedo, lo abre sin problema. Respecto al otro punto aun no lo pruebo, gracias.

Comment: Oye a la hora de dar click en el botón, se descarga el archivo , pero lo qué hace es que se descarga aunque no le haya metido valores a mi formulario y la consulta venga vacía, como puedo hacer para que cuando no tenga  datos no se descargue?  Tengo una validación en mi jsp con Javascript, el cual si doy click en el botón y no están llenos, manda un modal que dice que debes llenar los campos y al mismo tiempo se descarga el archivo, quiero que si no hay datos , no se descargue y diga en el modal, no hay datos